# Local site in apache just redirects to another localsite

Tags: apache, ubuntu, localhost, ubuntu-18.04

Using Ubuntu 18.04.01 and I set up multiple sites in apache so I can work on them locally. Here is my current set up:

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   site1.local
127.0.1.1   site2.local
```

/var/www

```
site1.com
site2.com
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available

```
000-default.conf
default-ssl.conf
site1.com.conf
site2.com.conf
```

site1.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com
    ServerName site1.local
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

site2.com.conf looks the same as this but swap 'site1' with 'site2'

I also ran:

```
sudo a2ensite site1.com.conf
sudo a2ensite site2.com.conf
```

and the symlinks in in /sites-enabled are now there.

However the behavior I get is when I go to my browser and typle in http://site1.local it loads just fine. But when I enter in http://site2.local the browser just redirects back to site1.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was just a caching issue with my browser